# Send and Receive large amount of data through tcp stream using read/write (Error)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, stream, network-programming

I am trying to receive data at my server of any length through tcp connection. First my client sends length of data to server through stream.write then it send the actual data.
At Client I receive the length and loop until whole the data is received successfully.

The problem is: "I receive 0 size on the server no matters what the length of data is". I tried to figure out the issue but could not get where the problem is. Any kind of help/hint would be appreciated.

Server Side Code:

```
byte[] lengthOfData = new byte[2048];
byte[] buffer;
try
{
    stream = client.GetStream();
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Size of 1st = "+stream.Read(lengthOfData,0,lengthOfData.Length));
    int numBytesToRead = ByteArraySerializer.BytesArrayToInt(lengthOfData);
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("number of bytes to read= "+numBytesToRead);
    buffer = new byte[numBytesToRead+10];
    int numBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        int n = stream.Read(buffer, numBytesRead, 10);
        numBytesRead += n;
        numBytesToRead -= n;
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("number of bytes read= " + numBytesRead);
    } while (numBytesToRead > 0);
 }
 catch (Exception e)     // Called automatically when Client Diposes or disconnects unexpectedly
 {
     eventLog1.WriteEntry("Connection Closes: "+e.ToString());
     lock (connectedClients)
     {
         connectedClients.Remove(client);
     }
     client.Close();

     break;
  }
```

Client Side Code

```
byte[] command = ByteArraySerializer.Serialize<Command>(cmd);
byte[] sizeOfData = ByteArraySerializer.IntToBytesArray(command.Length);
stream.Write(sizeOfData, 0, sizeOfData.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Size of Data = "+command.Length);
stream.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line at server

```
byte[] lengthOfData = new byte[2048];
```

to

```
byte[] lengthOfData = new byte[sizeof(int)];
```

The issue was that the read at server was supposed to read only 4 bytes integer whereas it was reading other data as well which was getting written after writing the length of data. We are supposed to read only 4 bytes if we want to get the length of data(integer).